# Issue copying files with NodeJS and GraphicsMagick

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphicsmagick

I'm about to scrap this current NodeJS project due to the amount of issues I've had doing something as simple as creating multi-resolution copies of images and watermarking one of them. I've spent days fighting with Node making this work which is ridiculous considering the same code in Ruby is only a few lines long and took a matter of minutes to write. However the company wants it in Node so here we go.

Using NodeJS, Express, Multer and GraphicsMagick I'm attemping to take a user uploaded HD image and create multiple smaller copies with the final thumbnail being watermarked. This in itself was relatively easy however when I started load testing with hundreds of rapid uploads I found that although the original images are uploaded I'm losing around 20% of the copied images. My guess about what was happening was the copying function was interrupted while writing to disk as the next upload came through and JavaScript was rewriting the filename or something along those lines.

As you can see in the code below I've created a new object each time the post handler is called which I had assumed would encapsulate the method variables and stop anything being overwritten. I honestly have no idea what JavaScript is doing here.

My testing method is a custom Bash script which posts a file through Curl. I've tested this on Ubuntu Xenial and Debian stable with the same result. The script that follows only uploads 20 images but the issue is still present, it expects 40 images returned but returns around 36:

```
#!/bin/bash

#simulates multiple image posts with different parameters
for run in {1..2}
do
    FNAME=("imageOne" "imageTwo" "imageThree" "imageFour" "imageFive" "imageSix" "imageSeven" "imageSeven" "imageEight" "imageNine" "imageTen")
    USER=("userOne" "userTwo" "userThree" "userFour" "userFive" "userSix" "userSeven" "userSeven" "userEight" "userNine" "userTen")
    for item in {0..9}
    do
        URL="http://localhost:3000/api/images/${USER[$item]}/${FNAME[$item]}"
        curl -i -F "image=@sample.png;type=image/png" $URL

# works when sleep called
#        sleep 1

    done
done
```

As it is says in the comment the code works perfectly when an interval is inserted before each upload which means the issue is due the asynchronous execution. Perhaps my callbacks are not waiting until confirmation of the file being written?

Here are the main methods. The Upload method uses Multer to upload the user image. FindSize takes the watermark and user image and finds dimensions for later processing and Watermark creates a copy of the original. I've removed all other functionality for the sake of this demo such as creating the watermark and resizing to different resolutions as it still suffers from the same issue.

```
"use strict";
var multer = require('multer'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    gm = require('gm');


function ProcessFile(req,res){

    var fname,
        fmime;

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {

            cb(null, './uploads/');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            fmime = '.' + file.mimetype.substr(6,file.mimetype.length);
            fname = req.params.user + '-' + Date.now() + '-' + req.params.filename;
            cb(null, fname + fmime);
        }
    });

    // multer option that controls which files are uploaded
    var fileFilter = function(req,file,cb)
    {
        // remove non-raster-image filetypes
        var mimetypes = ['gif','jpeg', 'png', 'bmp'];
        for (var mime in mimetypes)
        {
            if (file.mimetype == 'image/' + mimetypes[mime])
            {
                // accept file
                cb(null,true);
                return;
            }
        }
        // reject file
        cb(null,false);
    };

    var upload = multer({storage:storage, fileFilter:fileFilter, limits:{fileSize:1000000}}).single('image');


    var findSize = function(call){
        var yPos = 0,
            xPos = 0,
            self = this,
            width = 0,
            height = 0;

        // get width of watermark image
        function getWidth(c) {
            gm('watermark.png')
                .size(function (err, size) {
                    width = size.width;
                    height = size.height;
                    c(); // getMidPoint callback
                });
        }

        // finds horizontal mid point of image and calls main function
        function getMidPoint(c) {
            gm('./uploads/' + fname + fmime)
                .size(function (err, size) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    }
                    else {
                        yPos = size.height / 2;
                        xPos = size.width / 2;
                        c();
                    }
                });
        }

        getWidth(function c(){
            getMidPoint(function c(){
                call(yPos, xPos, width, height);
            });
        });

    };

    var watermark = function(yPos, xPos, width, height, call){
        // set watermark width to 60% of image width
        var markwidth = (xPos*2)* 0.6,
            xPlacement = xPos-(markwidth/2),
            yPlacement = yPos-(height/2),
            aspectHeight = (yPos*2)/(xPos*2) * markwidth,
            self = this;

        aspectHeight = Math.round(aspectHeight);
        // does nothing but create a copy for demo purposes
        gm('./uploads/'+fname + fmime)
        // write original image
            .write('./uploads/'+fname+'-'+markwidth+'x'+aspectHeight + fmime, function (err) {
                if (err){console.log(err)}
                else
                {
                    call();
                }
            });
    };


    this.run = function(req,res){
        upload(req,res, function(err){
            if(!err) {
                findSize(function call(yPos, xPos, width, height) {
                    watermark(yPos, xPos, width, height, function call() {
                        console.log('complete');
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
}

var p = new ProcessFile();

module.exports = p;
```

Here is the code for the route. The image processing methods are imported as the variable 'imageHandler'.

```
app.post('/api/images/:user/:filename', function(req,res){
    imageHandler.run(req,res);
    res.end();
});
```

I'm still trying to comprehend the benefits of an asynchronous, single threaded, event-driven language on a server which to me appears clearly ridiculous except in extraordinary circumstances.

Anyway if anyone can help with this it would be much appreciated otherwise I'm scrapping this and going back to rails.

Comment: _TL;DR_ but you most likely overwrite variables concurrently (I would guess at least `fname` and `fmime`), so test the following changes: remove `var p = new ProcessFile();`, and write `module.exports = function(req, res) {  var p = new ProcessFile(); p.run(req, res);  res.end(); }` instead of `module.exports = p;` and change your  `app.post('/api/images/:user/:filename',` to `app.post('/api/images/:user/:filename', imageHandler);`. I'm pretty sure this solves the problem.

Comment: Yup that was it. That's awesome that you can debug that so quickly. I knew I should have followed the Express documentation. If you want me to mark this correct then write a formal answer below and if you have a PayPal email I'll buy you a beer for saving my project.